# navigating to previous URL in lightning component

Tags: lightning

I need to go back to the previous URL on click of a button in lightning component.Currently I am using `window.history.back();` for the same. Is it good practice to use `window.history.back()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, window.history methods are allowed, so you should feel free to use them if they are appropriate to the task at hand.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox Does it stands good today as well in the context of Lightning web security

Comment: @lovegupta Yes, the history methods work with LWS.